# Keep Indexing when Sorting Vector c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am very new to c++ and can't find a way to keep track of my vector indexing after sorting an vector.

So far I have:

```
static bool sortlowtohighinternal(double u, double v) //internal use in sortlowtohigh
{
    return u < v;
}


vector<double> sortlowtohigh(vector<double> v){

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortlowtohighinternal);

    return v;
}
```

which will sort the `vector<double>` from low to high but it also reindexes the vector. Is it possible to get something like:

Input Vector: `{1.0, 3.0, 2.0}`

Output Sorted Vector: `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`

Output Of Indexes from Input Vector: `{1, 3, 2}`

Comment: I'm a bit curious as to why you need to keep the original indices?

Comment: What do you actually expect, indices of items may change during sorting of course.

Comment: Maybe they are trying to do some sort of matrix operation to retain what columns are swapped.

Comment: Could sort a list of indicies using the actual values for the comparator.